# Unable to Import Excel to Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am having a gridview with Export to Excel and Import Excel. However I can successfully export data from gridview and when I try to import to same excel, I am not able to import that excel to grid. But when I change the excel filename and import it works fine.

Can anyone suggest me why this happens? Below is my code to Import excel to grid.

```
protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sexcelconnectionstring = "";
    string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadExcel.FileName).ToLower();
    string path = FileUploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName;
    string query = "";
    Label1.Text = "";
    GridView2.Visible = false;

    if (strFileType != String.Empty)
    {
        //Connection String to Excel Workbook
        if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
        {
            sexcelconnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        }
        else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
        {
            sexcelconnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Open();

        System.Data.DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        string sheetname = dt.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();

        try
        {
            query = "SELECT [Size],[Order],[Ratio] FROM [" + sheetname + "]";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (objDA.IsValidExcelColumns(ds, GridView2, strSqlTable))
            {
                string sclearsql = "delete from " + strSqlTable;
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);
                sqlconn.Open();
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlconn.Close();

                //series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our sql table
                OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
                oledbconn.Open();
                OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(query, oledbconn);
                OleDbDataReader dReader;
                dReader = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
                SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnectionString);
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = strSqlTable;
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Data has been saved successfully.')", true);
            }

            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please validate the excel data.')", true);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded due to invalid column names.Please check: " + ex.Message;
        }

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        objDA.BindGrid(GridView1, "select * from " + strSqlTable);
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please select a file to import the data.')", true);
    }
}
```

Here is the code to export to excel.

```
protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strQuery = "select * from " + strSqlTable;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    System.Data.DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

    //Create a dummy GridView
    GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
     "attachment;filename=MyExcelData.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //Apply text style to each Row
        GridView1.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
    }
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

    //style to format numbers to string
    string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
    Response.Write(style);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: On which line does the error happen and what IS the error?

Comment: It happens on this line conn.Open(); right below sexcelconnectionstring. 
Error:
OleDbException was unhandled by user code. External table is not in the expected format.

Comment: As a suggestion: If you don'T have to load old xls files, you can safely use a library like epplus to load the file. it is magnitudes faster and much more reliable.

Comment: Probably I have to load xls files.

Answer (score -1):

Could you please specify how you are exporting data to excel. Are you using office INTEROP services to export data? If so, dispose the excel application object using garbage collector. Then try to import data from excel.

I think the cause is when you export data to excel file, a new excel.exe is created in Task Manager. After data export, if you didn't close the excel appl. object, It will still be in memory. So when you try to import same excel to grid, It throws an exception because the file is already in use and not disposed.

`using Marshal = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal;`
`To close excel application - excel.quit();`
`To dispose excel object - Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);`